# After adding mo localization files to WP 3.8.1 install backend shows new update to 3.8.1

Tags: updates, localization

I am running a standard WP install at version 3.8.1. I am at the finishing touches of the project and wanted to switch languages from english to german. I've downloaded the localization files from

http://wpde.org/download/sprachdateien/  then http://wpde.org/files/2012/05/de_DE.zip

afterwards i've placed the mo files into `wp-content/languages/`and activated alongside `de_DE` in the `wp-config.php`file. Everything works and all strings are shown localized properly.
My only problem is if i log into the backend the dashboard shows a new update to Wordpress 3.8.1, the version i am already running happily for weeks. ;) Is the reason for that behaviour that the localization files are from december 2013 and the 3.8.1 wp install from january 2014? And is it save to "reininstall" version 3.8.1 again over the existing version 3.8.1  . thought so far that the localization files are more or less independent from the core wp files.  thanks r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this lately. I saw that update to French version after I had just added fr_FR in the wp_lang variable of wp-config.pho. No need to go get the files, just click update :)

Comment: ah you mean an update includes localization files too as soon as you have added mo files for a specific language? that means since the localization files i've downloaded are for version 3.8.0 from december 2013 you get updated localization files with reupdating to 3.8.1 again even that you are already running 3.8.1? so more or less only the localization files are updated with the update?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the update included the proper files for the new language I selected.

All I did was switch the language variable in `wp-config.php`, then updated when the option appeared  ;)

As far as I remember, that’s how it happened.